# array with data is reduced and put in the spinner

Tags: android

have an an array

```
    String classname[]={'a','b','c','d'};
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterClasses = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item_class,
                R.id.spinnerclasstxt, classname);
        spnrClass.setAdapter(adapterClasses);
        spnrClass.setSelection(0);

        spnrClass
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int pos, long arg3) {
                        classname[0]="";
                        int selectedindex = pos;
                        if (selectedindex == 0) {
                            spnrSubject.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            spnrSubject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            selectedClass = classdetails.get(selectedindex - 1);

                            subjectpopulate(selectedClass);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    }

                });
`
```

but the result in dropdown should be
"b
c
d"
 help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is, before passing `classname[]` to spinner itself, filter what you don't want.

Sudo code is:  Convert array to List
                 list.remove(yourItem);
                 Iterate the list and construct array
                 Pass array to spinner.

I don't have IDE handy, Otherwise I could have posted sample code.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to add title to the spinner. can u help me with it?

Comment: What do you mean by add title to spinner? I didn't get it.

Comment: maybe you can use android:prompt. It sets title bar for the dropdown . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:prompt

Comment: something like adding adding hint in edit box!

Answer (score 1):

What is exact requirement? While defining your Spinner you are setting the index as 0 which is 'a', but you are expecting the dropdown window to display only 'b','c','d'. If this is the case then why are you setting the index as 0?

Again, if you want to filter your dropdown, you have to update your spinner adapter. But i suggest you to get the clear requirement.

Comment: because i want a to be displayed initially in the spinner but the spinner should not posses a when drop down